# Dynamically adding anchor to paragraph element is not working

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <p id="test"></p>
</div>
<script>
    var newLink = document.createElement('a'); // #1
    newLink.href = 'http://google.fr'; // #2
    document.getElementById('test').appendChild(newLink); // #3
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is not working, and I can't understand why.

1. I create a new element `<a>`
2. I add the href to this element (`<a href="http://google.fr">`)
3. I tell JS to go and find `test` and add this element to the `<p>` tag which has `test` as an ID.

**Why it is not working?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding some content to the element as well by setting the `.innerHTML` property. As it is now you are just adding an empty anchor. Try something like this:

```
var newLink = document.createElement('a');
newLink.href = 'http://google.fr';
newLink.innerHTML = 'My anchor';
document.getElementById('test').appendChild(newLink);
```

Comment: @barmar & Christofer Thank you!!

Answer (score -2):

Use `innerHTML` property to append the tag you created inside the paragraph tag.

Comment: This is wrong, and why is it posted as a bullet list? And please don't use IM language, you can spell out "you".

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem. The problem is that he doesn't create any text to click on.